# embedding $L(H_1) \hookrightarrow L(H_1 \otimes H_2)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras

Let $H_1, H_2$ be Hilbert spaces. Let $L(H_i)$ ,$L(H_1 \otimes H_2)$ denote  the bounded linear operators on the spaces.

> There is a canonical map 
>   $$L(H_1) \rightarrow L(H_1 \otimes H_2), \quad T\mapsto T \otimes I$$
>   then this map isometric $*$-homomorphism.

I wonder if there is a reference for the proof of the above statement.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true - this map is an isometric $*$-homomorphism, but it is not an isomorphism - it is not surjective.

Isometricity easily follows from the fact, that injective $*$-homomorphisms between $C^*$-algebras are isometric. This theorem can be found in most books on $C^*$-algebras, e.g. Davidson's book "$C^*$-algebras by example", theorem I.5.5.

Comment: Thanks, yes it was a typo, it is not an isomorphism.

Comment: I wonder if you also know a reference for theorem **I.8.6.1, pg 45** for https://wolfweb.unr.edu/homepage/bruceb/Cycr.pdf on the dual of compact operators on a hilbert space $H$.

Comment: This is theorem VI.26 in "Methods of modern mathematical physics I: Functional analysis" - Reed,  Simon. Formally they consider only separable Hilbert spaces, but I believe everything should work similarly in general case.